# Foundation 5 file structure and HTML markup

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm trying to use Foundation 5 with SASS. It comes with bower and grunt, but I don't know how I should use these files. This question might be related to "best practices", but I just need a quick recommendation here.

- Should I leave them in the `bower_components` folder and link to them from my web app or
- Should I manually copy them over to a simpler folder tree or
- Should I change the bower/grunt output folder to a simpler folder trees?

A simpler folder tree would be for example..

```
-css
  -vendor
    -modernizr.css
  -foundation.css
-js
  -vendor
    -jquery.js
  -foundation.js
-img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing much research, I decided to have a look at what some of the popular Yeoman generators do.

If we have a look at [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator, for example, there are two states: "dev" and "dist" (basically, development version and production version).

During development, we may use pre-compiled/pre-uglified scripts/styles (such as coffeescript, sass, stylus etc). But eventually, these will be processed to be production-ready.

While development, it is easy to refer to them from bower_components. But, after development, they probably eventually have to be compiled over to different folder.

In this case, we have SASS files of Foundation and some other necessary scripts in bower_components. While we can compile/minify these files within bower_components folder, the better way is to output these processed sources into a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I, for example, added an additional `.bowerrc` file with the content

```
{"directory" : "Resources/Private/BowerComponents"}
```

...because that fits into my framework's convention. From this, I only had to adapt the config.rb file accordingly and give sass hints to where to find the files.

You might also want to have a look at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-compass-template which is a plain package you can get started with (but beware of https://github.com/zurb/foundation-compass-template/issues/2 which is active at this state).

Comment: one more thing to relate your actual questions: I definitely wouldn't copy the files around because you loose the ability to `bower update` them. Just refernce them as good as possible (with `config.rb` as mentioned, for example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After I looked through some Yeoman generators, I realized many of these components are juggled around to fit either development or production purpose. I agree that we should refer to them in bower_component while in development so we can `bower_update` as you mentioned.